# How to display single product details in e-commerce website with React-js React-Router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-router-dom, router

I am creating an e-commerce website, I want to make a feature, where if the user clicks on a particular product, the user should be able to see the product details of that particular product. I want to implement this in react js with react-router dom, how should I pass the id and show the details of the particular product

**Product.jsx**

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
// import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import HotelData from "../src/HotelData.json"
import Icons from './components/Icons';
import Subscribe from '../src/components/Subscribe.jsx';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Hotel = () => {


  return (
    <>
      <section className='product'>
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='row'>
            {HotelData.product.map((value) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={value.id}>
                  <div className='col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 '>
                    <div className='cards'>
                      <Link  data-item-id={value.id} to={`/product/${value.id}`} >
                        <img src={value.img} alt="" />
                      </Link>
                      <div className='product-img-badges'>
                        <span className='pink'>{value.discount}</span>
                        <span className='purple'>{value.type}</span>
                      </div>
                      <div className='description'>
                        <div className='product-content-3'>
                          <p>{value.Text}</p>
                          <h6>{value.price} <del>{value['del-price']}</del></h6>
                          <div className="icon">
                            <Icons />
                          </div>
                          {/* <Button variant="contained">Contained</Button> */}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </React.Fragment>
              )
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <Subscribe />
    </>
  )
}

export default Hotel
```

**ProductDetails.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import HotelData from '../HotelData.json'
import Rating from '@mui/material/Rating';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Addcart from './Addcart';
import FacebookIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Facebook';
import SportsVolleyballIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SportsVolleyball';
import PinterestIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Pinterest';
import TwitterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Twitter';
import LinkedInIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LinkedIn';


    const ProductDetails = () => {
    
        return (
    
            <>
                <section className='product_details'>
                    <div className=' container'>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='top'>
                                <a href="/">Home</a>
                                <span> /</span>
                                <span to="product">SHOP PRODUCT</span>
                            </div>
                            {HotelData.productdetails.map((value) => {
                                return (
                                    <React.Fragment key={value.id}>
                                        <div className='d-flex gap-5 align-items-center'>
                                            <div className='img'>
                                                <img data-itemID={value.id} className='default-img' src={value.img} alt="" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className='details'>
                                                <h6>{value.Text}</h6>
                                                <p>{value.price} <span>{value.delprice}</span></p>
                                                <Stack spacing={1}>
                                                    <Rating name="half-rating" defaultValue={3} precision={0.5} />
                                                </Stack>
                                                <div className='del'>
                                                    <p>{value.details}</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className='add_cart'>
                                                    <Addcart />
                                                </div>
                                                <div className='categories'>
                                                    <h6>{value.cat}</h6>
                                                    <h6>{value.tag}</h6>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className='product-icon'>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="facebook"><FacebookIcon></FacebookIcon></a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="facebook"><SportsVolleyballIcon></SportsVolleyballIcon></a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="facebook"><PinterestIcon></PinterestIcon></a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="facebook"><TwitterIcon></TwitterIcon></a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="facebook"><LinkedInIcon></LinkedInIcon></a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                )
                            })}
    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </>
        )
    }
    
    export default ProductDetails
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../src/css/style.css'
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import NavbarMain from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import Collection from './pages/Collection';

import Blog from './pages/Blog';
import Contact from './pages/Contact';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
// import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Footernew from './components/Footernew';
import ProductDetails from './components/Product-Details';
// import Loader from './components/Loader';
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      {/* <Loader /> */}
      <NavbarMain />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path='/Home' element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path='/about' element={<About />} />
        <Route exact path='/collection' element={<Collection />} />
        <Route exact path='/product/' element={<ProductDetails />} />
        <Route exact path='/blog' element={<Blog />} />
        <Route exact path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footernew />

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This are some screenshot

[Here you can see we can see the id after hovering the product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCIVR.png)

[But we cannot get the details of a particular product id after clicking on the product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFfNU.png)

How can I show the details of a single product on another page? Pls help me I am stuck on this issue

Comment: have your `id` in Route as `<Route exact path='/product/:id' element={<ProductDetails />} />` then in the component fetch details getting the `id` from `useParams`

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-product-detail-pages-dynamic-links-tmcjc

It's simply

```
<Route exact path='/product/:productId' element={<ProductDetails />} />
```

Comment: But how it can be implemented? In the exemple you are giving you are matching with a dummy .js that suposed to be .json file. It is not seen as a good practice.